# Can I tile over Linoleum felt paper on a concrete slab?

Tags: concrete, tile, linoleum

I have a contractor coming in to tile my home.  My floor is a post tension concrete slab, home is only 4 yrs old.  The contractor said they could just tile right over the linoleum, but after reading about the risks online, I decided to rip it up and they said they would just tile right over whatever material is left.  I can easily rip up the top layer of the linoleum, but the felt/paper layer adheres to the concrete 100%.  Should I be spending time/money/energy on getting all the felt paper up as well?  or is the contractor right that there will not be any issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to apply a coat of embossing compound over a firmly bonded vinyl floor, then tile right over it. It certainly is not my favorite method, but as long as the existing vinyl is well adhered and not curling at sides etc. the tile should stay down well.

Since you have already removed most of the vinyl, I would not worry too much about some left behind backer. Get as much off as you can, and don't leave any loose paper. If any of the leftovers will soften easily with water, soak them a bit and remove it. Other than that, if it is stuck good, go ahead and tile over it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the felt is hurting anything since it is common to apply thinset to a common material in showers (Kerdi).  Basically you would be worried that the felt will keep the thinset from binding to the concrete.  Well it won't even without the felt.  It will fit snug either way but there is no binding.